# Kafka MirrorMaker between different versions with timestamp

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to use Kafka MirrorMaker to mirror all event from Kafka cluster version 0.8 to another Kafka cluster version 1.0, both clusters should stay production.

The problem is that old Kafka (version 0.8) stores messages without a timestamp field (the timestamp is part of the message).

I'm looking for a way that Kafka MirrorMaker could produce messages with timestamp to the Kafka cluster 1.0 that would be extracted from the message (event time rather processing time).

Does anyone have idea how to do it with Kafka mirromaker or some other tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mirrormaker 0.8 to bring the data to the 1.0 cluster then do the transformation with a kafka streams application or a mirrormaker message handler using the 1.0 version and an intracluster mirror. Here's an example message handler. https://github.com/gwenshap/kafka-examples/blob/master/MirrorMakerHandler/src/main/java/com/shapira/examples/TopicSwitchingHandler.java

Either way, if you want the timestamp in the message, you have to bring it over to the 1.0 cluster first, then process it there. Otherwise you're looking at having some application read and parse the message on one version and then creating a new record on the new version of the message format. This leaves you limited ability to reprocess. I'd just pull the old data into the new cluster and make a new topic for the new data format while you phase out the old format.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, mirror maker can't read a timestamp of Kafka prior to 0.10 when it was added.

NiFi and Streamsets don't offer support for setting the record timestamps (yet).

Your best option would require you to deserialize the messages from a consumer, extract timestamps within the record, and create and send a ProducerRecord with that timestamp. Spark/Flink would be optimal to make it go fast

Answer (score 0):

You may want to configure the **KafkaTopic** on to  which data is mirror-made to have `message.timestamp.type=LogAppendTime`. 
When the data from *v0.8.X* is read, as you know, it will not have any timestamp. When the MirrorMaker script publishes this message on to *V0.10.X* (or higher), which has `message.timestamp.type=LogAppendTime` configured, the timestamps will be recorded.

Comment: That is bad solution, because in case of lag new published messages would shift in time(processing time), the better approach is to us message handler to extract event time